# modeling related information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, data-modeling

Let's say we have a user model. We also have the concept of a "subscription" that contains a plan_id (maybe 2 subscription fields total). Please tell me what you think of the following approaches of modeling this. Should I always create a separate model whenever I can?

1. Shove all subscription-related information into the
   user model. Have two resources subscription and user which both
   operate on the user model.
2. Have two separate models and resources. In each resource update only
   the respective model.

I gravitate more towards 2, but I wanted to hear some feedback as to why 1 is bad. I'd also like to hear when you can deviate from a 1-to-1 mapping between resources and models.

Comment: How would you describe the relationship between users and subscriptions?  This is what would ultimately drive your code.  Does a user always have exactly one subscription?  Could a user have many subscriptions?  Describing in text the relationship between various objects should tell you how those objects need to relate in your rails application.

Comment: I'm expecting 0 or 1 subscriptions per user. It'd be hard otherwise to use just the users table.